# please explain what happens when you access a jQuery object directly?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

For example:

```
$('.something')[0]
```

I've been working with javascript for about a year now and I see this sometimes in various projects' codebase... What does it mean and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

`$(".class")` selector selects all elements with the specific class. Internally, it uses `getElementsByClassName()` to traverse the DOM and retrieve the elements. That method  returns "an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names". Hence, `$('.something')[0]` is simply retrieving the first element off that array. It will hold the very first HTML DOM element with that class (since you might have *many elements* having that class, right?). Type of `$('.something')[0]` will be `object`.